# How can I catch and reroute a url with a specific querystring parameter in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

i have a controller named `PagesController` which used to have an action named `contest`. In this action I would check for the existence of a `thanks` param and serve up a thank you page if it was present. I've since abstracted that single action into a model and controller of it's own and I now want to redirect any requests for `/contest?thanks` to `/contests/thanks`. What is the best way to do this? So far I've tried the following in my `routes.rb` file, but it doesn't work:

```
# Redirect old URLs
match '/contest' => redirect("/contests")
match '/contest?thanks' => redirect("/contests/thanks")
```

Comment: We have some 3rd party resources that are already configured to redirect a contest form submission to `/contest?thanks`. Hindsight is 20-20...

Comment: Is it important that the redirect will be from routes.rb? Can't you redirect from the controller?

Comment: I would be OK with that, as long as I can catch it somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect from the controller -

config/routes.rb:

```
match "/contest" => "contest#old_route"
```

app/controllers/contest_controller.rb:

```
def old_route
    if params[:thanks]
       redirect_to "/contests/thanks"
    else
       redirect_to "/contests"
    end
end
```

HTH

Answer (score 2):

If you want to deal with this entirely in routes.rb this route would work:

```
match '/contest' => redirect { |params, request|
  if request.params.has_key?(:thanks)
     "/contests/thanks"
  else
     "/contests"
  end
}
```

Comment: This solution just saved my life (and many hours of hair pulling)! Tx!